# iOS Bluetooth: What happens to device when it switches role from central to peripheral?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I am doing some research on pairing two iOS devices together. Suppose that both devices have speakers and keyboards paired to them. What will happen to the paired devices when a device switches role from central to peripheral? Will the paired devices remain connected or will they get dropped?
Best,
Julian

Comment: You may get a better response to this question on the Super User website.

Comment: An iOS device can act as a Bluetooth low energy central and peripheral at the same time. Also, the types of peripherals you mention are legacy devices, not BLE so they would be unaffected by any apps running in central/peripheral mode